# String must match 7 digits and optional non consecutive characters from set

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to match if it only contains [-+./()] and digits. The non digits must not have two consecutive matches. The string must also contain 7 digits in total.

ie

- `((` is invalid.
- `(` is also invalid
- `(1234567)+` is valid and
- `()1+34564+0` is also valid

I've written this following regex:
`/^(([()/.+ -])\1?(?!\2)|\d)*$/`

The part that is not working for me is, the mandatory digits. I am not sure how to complete the the regex. How should the regex look for the above rules?

Comment: Is there a requirement that all the business rules must be represented by a  single regex? If not, it may be cleaner to just have the digit count as a separate test.

Comment: Yes, the requirement is it must be in one regex

Comment: Is this homework?  =)

Comment: No, it's work related

Comment: May you provide more examples? To me the part "non digits must not have two consecutive matches" is unclear, since `()1+34564+0` is valid.

Comment: I think the meaning is that the non-digits cannot have two consecutive matches to themselves. So, (( is not valid and )) is not valid, but () is. Is that right?

Comment: @Nikki9696 is correct

Comment: Try [`^(?=(?:\D*\d){7}\D*$)(?:\(\d*\)\d*|\d+)(?:[+\/*-](?:\(\d*\)|\d+))*[+\/*-]?$`](https://regex101.com/r/gC0rW4/3).

Comment: It shouldn't match ```0121+1234+123```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does the job:

```
^(?:(?:([-+./()])(?!\1))*\d){7}(?:([-+./()])(?!\2))*$
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lookahead to validate the presence of 7 digits :

```
(?=\D*(\d\D*){7}$)
```

Placed at the beginning of your regex, it will make sure the matched String contains exactly 7 digits.

As a whole regex, I would use `^(?=\D*(\d\D*){7}$)(?:(?:([-()+./])(?!\2))|\d)*`. You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/sG4iV8/4).

Comment: Can you show how to combine this with the other expression?

Comment: Yes, but I'm rewriting a whole regex since a few things don't make sense in OP's regex. I'm in the process of doing so.

Comment: @Aaron You have to escape the hyphen or put it at the beginning of the square brackets.